# how to setup firebase dyanmicLink use Scheme only (iOS)

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, ios-universal-links

how to setup firebase dynamic-links use Scheme only?
for some reason, I can't use dynamic-links, and i need firebase's dynamic-links, so the only way to i can do is find out how to create dynamic-links with Schemes only.

i have asked the firebase for support about does they can use scheme only to create dynamic-links, the answer is yes, But i didn't find the way to setup use Scheme only
so i want to know firebase support scheme only to create dynamic-links or not? and if support how to setup?